# D3 : best way to find max value in a JSON object

Tags: json, d3.js, max

What's the best way to find the maximum value of `n2` (450) in this `dataJSON3` object using d3.js?

```
var dataJSON3 = {
  set1 : [
    {"nom":"Allemagne", "n1":200, "n2":86, "n3": 30},
    {"nom":"Allemagne", "n1":120, "n2":156, "n3": 40},
    {"nom":"France", "n1":117, "n2":34, "n3": 35},
    {"nom":"Italie", "n1": 309, "n2":12, "n3": 6},  
  ],  
  set2 : [
    {"nom":"Suisse", "n1":60, "n2":86, "n3": 30},
    {"nom":"Allemagne", "n1":90, "n2":450, "n3": 40},
    {"nom":"France", "n1":1000, "n2":34, "n3": 35},
    {"nom":"Italie", "n1": 440, "n2":12, "n3": 6},  
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find the max of exactly this json structure, you can do it like this:

```
var maxValue = d3.max([  // Find the max value of a list of 2 elements
    d3.max(dataJSON3.set1, function(d) { return d.n2; }), // Find the max value in `set1`
    d3.max(dataJSON3.set2, function(d) { return d.n2; })  // Find the max value in `set2`
]);
```

For a dynamic number of sets, you'll need to iterate through each property, find its max value and then find the max values among each property's max value:

```
var maxValuesPerSet = [];
for (var property in dataJSON3) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        maxValuesPerSet.push(d3.max(dataJSON3[property], function(d) { return d.n2; }));
    }
}
var maxValue = d3.max(maxValuesPerSet);
```

Comment: Thanks julian. And for "n" sets?

Comment: @LeSparte I've updated my answer with a generic solution.

Comment: @LeSparte, I'm glad it helped you. Do you mind marking it as the accepted answer? So that other people who face the same problem know that this solution works. Best regards!

Comment: I just upvoted your answer, iulian, and would accept it if it was allowed. That's actually something that I thought about asking on meta: allowing users with billions of RPs to accept answers in other people's questions.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thx mate. Did you ask this question on meta? I kind of intuit why there's no such a possibility, although it would be great to see what the long term community members think about it.

Comment: I didn't asked this yet, buy I'll will. And I'll let you know how many dozens of downvotes I receive! Cheers.